# Assets 6.4 HTTP API - Upload asset

Tags: api, upload, aem, assets

In the AEM Assets documentation it is written that a new asset can be created with the following POST request:

```
POST /api/assets/myFolder/* -F"name=myAsset.png" -F"file=@myPicture.png"
```

What is expected as a value for file property? I have tried uploading it with a path to the image, but every time I try to create an asset I end up creating a new folder.

What is the correct way to upload an asset via HTTP API?

Comment: What is the output in AEM logs?